# Outlook rule filtering based on TO field of the mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to set a rule such that it filters the mail based on the TO field of the mail.

The only condition that I found even remotely similar is 'Where my name is in the TO box'

I know that If you have multiple e-mail accounts, "me" refers to the e-mail address of any of your accounts, not just the account that is currently active.

The thing is, I need to restrict the rule to just one of my accounts and ignore the other(my main account) altogether.

I 'd avoid VBA in Outlook if I can help it, but if there's no other way. I would like to have the option as well.

Can anyone help with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about 'Where my name is in the TO box' and 'with specific word in the recipients address'?

Comment: Awesome!! Thank You very much. 
I would like to know though, how to fetch the recipient using VBA.
I tried the below but didnt get output

Set recips = oMailItem.Recipients
For Each recip In recips
Debug.Print recip.Name
Next